# Mouse clicks don't register about 50% of the time

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Precision 5530 laptop.  It has a Intel® Xeon(R) E-2176M CPU, 32GB of RAM, a 256GB NVME SSD.

The problem I'm having is that often, and it seems to be about 50% of the time, a mouse click doesn't register and then I have to click again.  Sometimes I have to click a 3rd time.  In a few instances it seems like those missed clicks get "caught up" and items that toggle will bounce a few times.  Mouse movement on the screen is not a problem and the scroll wheel seems to work as expected.

My current mouse of a Logitech M515 wireless but the same behavior is seen with the built-in touchpad as well and several other wired and bluetooth mice I have tried.

I've tried messing with the mouse settings although there are very few options there but nothing has changed.

I am sure this is not a hardware problem as this laptop also runs Windows 10 (via an SSD swap) and the mouse clicks work perfectly.

Do you have any ideas for me to try or solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a issue related on booting. so please follow these steps:
Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then go to a line which starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. at last after quiet splash add "i8042.nomux i8042.noloop" without quotes then reboot your device and your problem should be fixed....

The video is also available here : [Video Link](https://youtu.be/I2rHRi2ll9Q)

Thank You. There may be another method too

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it had no effect on the mouse behavior.

Comment: Then try updating your system and updating your drivers, re-connecting your mouse. Disable and re-enable mouse

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how to do that?

Comment: To update your system please execute: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y||||


To update driver open "additional drivers" app if update is available it will show it up
And then let me know it worked

Comment: @UbuntuUser Additional Drivers is ONLY for proprietary drivers. For graphics drivers it means Nvidia as ALL the other graphics use open source drivers that are automatically installed.

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion didn't work.  I solved my issue by changing to a different mouse.  It's not clear why the Logitech works fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu but the other one, a Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse, works fine in either.

Answer (score 0):

CTL + ALT + F1 and then CTL + ALT + F7 to switch between graphical and terminal interfaces seems to work around this problem for a while.

It's not a perfect solution, but it beats clicking like a 3x to get a single double click done.

From my vantage point on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 install, it seems like the Window loses focus. Even while typing this message, I need to click once to select the Browser, then click again to enter into this text box even though I'm typing in it and the cursor is already here.

One other thing to check is a Wireless mouse sometimes has issues when the battery runs down or the transceiver is plugged in on the far side of your laptop.